# Randomly through "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'" error during web-scraping a list of urls

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a list of URL which I like to loop through and scrape them. My code works fine for each URL alone! Though when I loop through the list, it starts giving me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/path/x.py", line 41, in <module>
   match = soup.find('div', id="threat").text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

This error each time shows up in a random URL from the list. Once it through the error in the third URL, once second, once fifth. I checked all URLs alone and nothing wrong with the code and scraping them alone!

Any idea what happens here?

```
for i in range(len(lines)):
    x = lines[i]
    source_ = requests.get(x).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source_, 'lxml')
    match = soup.find('div', id="threat").text
    with open('microsoftScrapped.txt', 'a') as out:
        out.write('\n' + '\n' + '\t' + '\t' + '\t' + "====== " + " #: " + str(num)  + "   " + x + " ======" + '\n' + '\n')
        out.write(match)
        print(num)
        print(x)
        num+=1
```

Comment: try to change `match = soup.find('div', id="threat").text` with `match = soup.find('div', attrs = {'id':'threat'}).text`

Comment: Again same error!
match = soup.find('div', attrs={'id': 'threat'}).text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: `requests.get(x).text` delete text in here

Comment: TypeError: object of type 'Response' has no len()

Comment: The strange thing is that each time this error shows up in a random URL! Even when I changed to match = soup.find('div', attrs={'id': 'threat'}).text

Comment: @Mahhos share your website url.

Comment: Any thought on this?